# HTML form data to XML and vice versa

Tags: html, xml

I have followed this tutorial and uploaded this on to my website and i am getting errors i would like to follow this example and understand it and create my own form that can save data to xml file and also display the xml data in the html page

[my website page for the above tutorial uploaded link is this](http://singaporetelugusamajam.org/entercontact.html)

The processform.asp code exactly in the server is as follows

http://www.xmlfiles.com/articles/michael/htmlxml/default.asp--> as the processform.asp no less no more

i am just getting error with out the error explanation i am new to this pls be clear in your answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial to be really useful and solved my problem but this requires C# proramming experience which i posses briefly
so this is the website
http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/XML/SaveformdatatoXMLfile.htm

you have to enable IIS on your windows system and run this by putting in the inetpub/wwwroot/(your own foldername)/(file name saved as .aspx)
 also make sure that inetpub folder in the C: drive is granted permissions for IISUSers this can be done by following the below steps

right click the inetpub folder and go to security tab and click edit and click add and click advanced and click findnow and find IIS_IUSRS and grant full permissions to it so as to create the book.xml file dynamically

Then go to ur fav internet browser and type localhost/(your own foldername)/(file name saved as .aspx). Then you can see the page in action if any queries feel free to ask me personally i will try to help you to the best of my knoweledge.. 
I am not sure why people gave a negative point to this question